# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/Path when dependency is in buiild.sbt

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have following setup in **build.sbt**:

```
lazy val proj = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "Proj",
    resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal,
    libraryDependencies += "javax.ws.rs" % "javax.ws.rs-api" % "2.1" artifacts( Artifact("javax.ws.rs-api", "", "jar")), // for rescu
    libraryDependencies += "com.github.mmazi" % "rescu" % "2.0.2",
  )
```

But `sbt run` give this error:

```
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/Path
[error]     at si.mazi.rescu.RestInvocationHandler.<init>(RestInvocationHandler.java:61)
```

while `Path` class exists in archive:

```
$ jar -tvf /home/user/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar | grep Path
   ...
   456 Fri Aug 04 15:17:40 MSK 2017 javax/ws/rs/Path.class
```

rs api added in this hacky way because otherwise it refused to plug, but now it seems to plug in, but I have no idea what could be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error I ended up with following set of dependencies which resolved this issue:

```
libraryDependencies += "javax.ws.rs" % "javax.ws.rs-api" % "2.1" artifacts( Artifact("javax.ws.rs-api", "", "jar") ),
libraryDependencies += "javax.ws.rs" % "jsr311-api" % "1.1.1",
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.cxf" % "cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs" % "3.3.1",
libraryDependencies += "com.github.mmazi" % "rescu" % "2.0.2",
```